# Automating LetsEncrypt Certificate Installation on shared server

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

Is it possible to programmatically installing LetsEncrypt Certificate on shared server, by using some opensource tool or PHP. Currently I'm generating Certificate on windows machine with "letsencrypt-win-simple" tool with W option which uses webdav to authenticate server. Certificate are generated locally in my windows machine and I've to configure it manually through cpanel every month.

Is it any possible automation for this process on certificate installation?

Comment: Voting to migrate because despite the OP asks for a PHP solution, the question is related to server administration and is best suitable for SF, where the community of experts may suggest a solution not necessarily in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Cpanel's API to install the new certificate. Here is a Linux example, but `curl` exists for Windows as well. You would need to change the paths in this script though:

```
domain='example.org'
ledir="/etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain"
cabundle="$ledir/chain.pem"
crt="$ledir/cert.pem"
key="$ledir/privkey.pem"

cpanel_host='cpanel.example.com:2083'
cpanel_user=''

curl -u "$cpanel_user"\
 "$cpanel_host/json-api/cpanel?cpanel_jsonapi_apiversion=2&cpanel_jsonapi_module=SSL&cpanel_jsonapi_func=installssl&cpanel_jsonapi_user=$cpanel_user"\
 -d "domain=$domain" --data-urlencode "cabundle@$cabundle" --data-urlencode "crt@$crt" --data-urlencode "key@$key"
```

This will still ask for your password. But it is possible to provide Curl with the password as well: `curl -u "user:password" ...`

Comment: This is what ive wanted. Lets hope it should work with php curl from shared hosting service. I've gone through cpnale json api and trying to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

you should look windows "sheduled tasks"

https://sites.google.com/site/ballif1073/windows/taches-planifiees

command line Example, not sure its working as i wrote it from the doc on my linux systeme :) (run task every month):

```
C:\>SCHTASKS /Create /SC MONTHLY /TR C:\path\to\letsencrypt-win-simple.exe
```